# How to get a numerical value of a date with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a value `0.000347222222222222` in a cell, which when formatted as time, looks like `30/12/1899 00:00:30` .

How to get it's numerical value with Google Apps Script?

`sheet.getRange('A1').getValue()` returns `Fri Dec 29 14:09:51 GMT+00:09 1899` .

Comment: It's not clear what the OP has tried. The question shows a Google Apps Script expression and a result, but it's unclear where the OP has seen that result. At first sight, the question doesn't make sense, as the expression included in the question should return the same cell value because it's a number. Please describe the relevant spreadsheet parts, be clear about the value displayed in the formula value and the value displayed in the cell, add a complete function and specify where the result of the expression is being observed (the Google Apps Script debugger, execution logs, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to do with formatting. When you get the value from Cell A1, it will carry the format with it. So if A1 is formatted as "date", "time" or "date time", then so will the cell that you copy it into. On the other hand, if you format cell A1 as "Scientific", then the format of the target cell will also be "Scientific".

Unfortunately the term "Scientific" isn't recognised as a number format, so a creative work around is required.

In order to do this programmatically, try this:

---

```
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // setup cell A1
    // value = 0.000347222222222222
    // formatting is irrelvant
  var rangea1 = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var valuea1 = rangea1.getValue();
  
  //setup target cell = Cell C1
  var rangec1 = sheet.getRange('C1');
  // assign content of A1 to C1
  rangec1.setValue(valuea1);

  // format the target cell as scientific 
  rangec1.setNumberFormat('0.###############')
  
  return;
}
```

---

`setNumberFormat` - [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat). Number formatting is described in the [API doc ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns)

Comment: Formatting is relevant. If the cell is formatted as date, time, date-time, duration, `sheet.getRange('A1').getValue()` will return a JavaScript Date object instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply it by 1

```
sheet.getRange('A1').getValue() * 1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).